# What are the difference between maxlife and maxrenewlife in kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

I want to know if I set maxlife to three day, but my ticket issued only a day. So I want t o know the difference between maxlife and maxrenewlife.

Answer (score 1):

from the kadmin man pages

```
-maxlife maxlife
(getdate time string) The maximum ticket life for the principal.
-maxrenewlife maxrenewlife
(getdate time string) The maximum renewable life of tickets for the principal.
```

you can use these options while doing the add_priciple